# Why is my solution to this particular word problem incorrect?

Tags: word-problem

I have a situation with 3 cars: A, B, and C. Cars B and C start at the same spot, while car A is already 15km ahead:

[image]

The velocities of the cars are:

$V_A = 50km/h$
$V_B = 40km/h$
$V_C = 60km/h$

The question is: is it possible that car C can be located exactly between car B and car A? The final answer dictates that the situation is not possible, but the equation I made suggests that it is, so I assume I made a mistake somewhere, but I can't seem to find where.

Here is how I did it:

Assume $t$ is the number of hours it took for the requested situation to occur:

[image]

It is obvious now that car C is just an average of the distances traveled by car A & B. If a solution exists, the following equation must be true:

$$\frac{(50t + 15) + 40t}{2} = 60t$$

When we try to solve for $t$, we get that:

$$90t + 15 = 120t \rightarrow 30t = 15 \rightarrow t = 1/2 \text{ hours}$$

If a solution exists, then the situation must occur -- this contrasts the final answer. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your reasoning looks good and your answer checks: the cars are at positions $40$, $20$ and $30$. Are you sure you stated the problem correctly and quoted the "answer" correctly?

Comment: I have triple checked and everything is in order. My only conclusion is that the final answer (which is not expanded upon) must be incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  After $\frac 12$ hour, $A$ is at $40$ km, $B$ is at $20$ km, $C$ is at $30$ km and $C$ is indeed halfway in between.